# Is there a meaningful difference between Aristotle's reasoning through induction and reasoning through example in chap 23-24 in prior analytics?

Tags: logic, aristotle

Aristotle presents reasoning through induction and reasoning through example as two different methods in chapters 23 and 24 of the *Prior Analytics*. He claims that induction is valid on the grounds that it apprehends every instance of a particular to reason to a universal. In reasoning through example one does not apprehend every instance of a particular to draw a universal. Since in practice we are unable to apprehend every instance of a particular is there a meaningful distinction between induction and the first step of example?

Answer (score 1):

See *Pr.An*, II.23:"For induction proceeds through an enumeration of all the cases."

Example, instead, is based on similarity; see II.24: "Conviction of this is obtained from similar cases, e.g. that the war against the Phocians was an evil to the Thebans. Since then to fight against neighbours is an evil, and to fight against the Thebans is to fight against neighbours, it is clear that to fight against the Thebans is an evil. [...] It differs from induction, because induction starting from all the particular cases proves that [...], whereas argument by example does not draw its proof from all the particular cases."

We have to note that in both cases it is not the relation of a *particular* to an *universal*: it is the relation of an universal to a wider one.

*Terms* in A's syllogistic are always universal. See II.24: "Clearly then an example stands neither as part to whole, nor as whole to part, but rather as part to part, when both are subordinate to the same term, and one of them is familiar."